# How to solve this error: Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. -MacBook-Pro.local is a loopback address in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I have done few settings on my system

1. add IP address of remote_host in JMeter properties file

> remote_hosts= ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx, ec2-user@x.x.xxx.xx

2. created rmi_keystore.jks file and copy paste this file into both slave machine's jmeter/bin folder
3. now when i am trying to run sh jmeter-server, its giving error
   [image]

can anyone help how can i solve it so it can connect with remote machines. or i am missing something which i should do it.

My firewall is already ON

Answer (score 0):

Amend your command to explicitly set [`java.rmi.server.hostname` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html)

```
sh jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP address or DNS hostname of your slave machine
```

and make sure that it's **not** `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `::1`

In order to make the change permanent you can add the above line to [JMeter *system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
java.rmi.server.hostname=IP address or DNS hostname of your slave machine
```

Alternatively you can add the next line to your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file:

```
Nehas-Macbook-Pro.local    IP address or DNS hostname of your slave machine
```

Comment: shall i put master machine ip address in remote_host in jmeter properties file in slave machines?

Comment: i tired to connect my system as master and slave then it worked but with remote machines, its not working